# How can I set the selected option of the select box after using exFilterColumn

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

So what I want to do is to pre-select few filters depending on the parameters of the location.search

Example Url : `index.html?Type=Building&Stage=Stage 2`

Here is my code

```
var searchObj = searchToObj(); // {Type: 'Building', Stage: 'Stage 2'};
var presetFilters = [];

for (var filterName in searchObj){
    if (filterName != 'search') {
        var filterID = oTable.column(filterName+':name').index();
        presetFilters.push([filterID, searchObj[filterName]]);
    }
}

yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, presetFilters);
```

The table is filtered but the select boxes stay on the default label.
What can I do?

Comment: are you calling this code inside `$(document).ready(function () {}` , I need a test page that reproduces the issue in order to help

Comment: I have the code here https://github.com/spark942/my-colony-reference/blob/master/script.js#L820-L830 if it helps

Comment: You need to remove all your extra code related to filtering, just construct the table and init yadcf, and see who it goes, then add code block after another to see what causes the issue...